# How to create a loop for merging several datasets for the evaluation of all the possible combinations (two-, three-, multi-class)

Tags: r, loops, rbind

I'm writing a code that provides an output with different matrices according to the different classes involved in the classification model I'm working on. So, I obtain a bunch of datasets (the number is not defined) with the same column names (i.e. same classes) and identified by the factor reported in the column "factor". I'd like to obtain all the multiple combinations of them in order to compare multiple classifications and find out which would be the best. Here is reported an example of what I'd like to achieve (for the example, when evaluating 3 classes, i.e. 3 different datasets):

```
frame_x = data.frame(a=c(12,10,3), b=c(6,4,2), c=c(3,62,3),factor=c("x","x","x"))
frame_y = data.frame(a=c(2,13,34), b=c(22,13,36), c=c(22,13,34),factor=c("y","y","y"))
frame_z = data.frame(a=c(36,28,11), b=c(32,24,16), c=c(33,22,17),factor=c("z","z","z"))

frame_x_new = rbind(frame_x,frame_y,frame_z)
frame_x_new$factor = c("x","x","x","other","other","other","other","other","other")
frame_y_new = rbind(frame_y,frame_x,frame_z)
frame_y_new$factor = c("y","y","y","other","other","other","other","other","other")
frame_z_new = rbind(frame_z,frame_x,frame_y)
frame_z_new$factor = c("z","z","z","other","other","other","other","other","other")

frame_x<-frame_x_new
frame_y<-frame_y_new
frame_z<-frame_z_new
```

Here's what I'd like to obtain in case I have 3 datasets, to test the different combinations of x vs y+z, y vs x+z and z vs x+y.
**I'd like to use a loop for doing this** since I might have also a higher (eg. 4 datasets, where I'd like to have x vs y+z+w, etc) or a lower (e.g. 2 datasets, x vs y) number of data frames. Also, the number of variables involved might be different according to the datasets under evaluation.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function does what the question asks for.
It takes 2 arguments

- `pattern` is a regex pattern for the data frames' names.
- `sep` separates the df's names and defines a suffix.

Note that the original data sets will be changed.

```
fun <- function(pattern, sep = "_"){
  frame_list <- ls(pattern = pattern, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  suffix <- sapply(strsplit(frame_list, sep), '[[', 2)
  df_list <- mget(frame_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  sa <- seq_along(df_list)
  res <- lapply(sa, function(i){
    n <- nrow(df_list[[i]])
    tmp <- do.call(rbind, df_list[c(i, sa[-i])])
    tmp$factor <- c(rep(suffix[i], n),
                    rep("other", nrow(tmp) - n))
    row.names(tmp) <- NULL
    tmp
  })
  names(res) <- frame_list
  list2env(res, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

fun("^frame")
```

Comment: Dear @Rui, it was actually what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your help!